# mootools html and css maniplation help

Tags: javascript, mootools, dom-manipulation

I have the following HTML

```
<div class="goto_step3">
<a href="<?= $this->sitePfx ?>/cart/paypal/" id="js_checkout_now" class="arrow">Checkout &amp; Pay</a>
<? if($this->discountCodeErrorMessage): ?>
    <p class="error discountError"><?= $this->discountCodeErrorMessage ?></p>
<? endif; ?>
<div class="discountCode fncFixedHeight <?= $this->has_discount ? 'redeemed': ''; ?>">
<? if(!$this->has_discount): ?>
    <label for="inptdiscountcode">Enter discount code</label>
    <input class='fncInpDiscountCode' id="inptdiscountcode" type="text" name="discount_code" value="" />
<? else: ?>
    <? if(!(empty($this->discount['discount_message']))): ?>
    <?= $this->discount['discount_message']; ?>
    <? else: ?>
    Voucher code redeemed
    <? endif; ?>
<? endif; ?>
```

On DomReady I want mootools  to make `.discountCode` `display:none` and also `.goto_step3 p` `display:none` , on clicking the link I want the `display:none` to become `display:block`

Any help would be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should hide the elements on dom ready and make them visible when the link is clicked.

```
window.addEvent('domready', function() {

    // you can pass multiple selectors to $$ each separated with a comma
    $$('.discountCode, .goto_step3 p').setStyle('display', 'none');

    $$('.goto_step3 a').addEvent('click', function() {
        $$('.discountCode, .goto_step3 p').setStyle('display', 'block');
    });

});
```

Comment: this in the context of the click function is bound to the A which is already visible... should be `this.getNext().setStyle("display", "block");` to target the P